# PySerial readline() first returns command, then the answer

Tags: python, pyserial

I have programmed a device (Trinket M0 3V) to interface with Python over a virtual COM port. When I test it in a serial monitor it works just fine, but when I switch to PySerial I run into problems. Specifically, I do the following:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial(physicalAddress, timeout = 5)
command = 'bogus\r'.encode()
ser.write(command)
response = ser.readline()
```

The `response` that I get is just the command I've written on the line preceding it. However, when I execute `ser.readline()` again I *do* get the response that I need. Since everything works fine when I try communicating on my serial monitor it suggests that there's something I'm missing in my use of PySerial, but that's about as far as I'm able to get.

Answer (score 2):

Did you find the infos of https://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/pyserial-unexpected-local-echo.711453/ ?
It had to be linked to the way the echo is handled, and the link gives steps to see if the echo is local or distant, and more...
I didn't find anything about a local echo done by PySerial!
But on the serial monitor (which one?), it seems to be possible to configure it, hence the reason you didn't see it!? (https://community.platformio.org/t/solved-enable-just-local-echo-in-serial-monitor/539)

Comment: I hadn't found those links, so thanks! Based on what I'm reading there it is very unlikely that the echo I get is caused by my (ab)use of PySerial, and is probably done by the device. This is a useful starting point for figuring out what PuTTY does but PySerial doesn't.